# Synchronize changes of service variable that changes in time angular 10

Tags: angular, service, constructor, synchronized, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to consume the following service in `Angular 10`, that is a service that looks for http requests in progress, this service changes from true to false if there are http requests, this does it fine, I check it with the console log

```js
export class SpinnerService implements HttpInterceptor {

  public loading: boolean = false;
  
  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loading = true;
    // console.log('estado spinner: >> ', this.loading);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.loading = false; 
        // console.log('todas solicitudes ok');
        console.log('estado espinner: >>', this.loading);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

When I am trying to consume the service in another component I have problems because the service is not synchronized with the local variable of the component.
For example, the loading variable of the service starts false, then it becomes true then it becomes false all this in a period of time of 5 seconds that takes the rest of the API to bring the data.

The load variable is initially synchronized with the loading variable as false, but then it does not follow the states of the loading variable, the load variable remains false

How do I synchronize these variables? help please, I don't know how to search

This is the constructor where I call the service from the loading variable,

```js
public carga = this._spinnerService.loading;
    
constructor(private _spinnerService: SpinnerService) 
{
  this.crearFormulario();  // inicializar formulario
  // this._spinnerService.loading = this.spinneres;
  // console.log('estado inicial spinner: >>', this._spinnerService.loading);
  console.log('estado inicial spinner: >>', this.carga);
}
```

Comment: Ok the value is set to true just inside the intercept function.  It's then set to false as soon as any http request returns.  The question is how many requests does it process and what is the time difference?  Chances are that it's happening so fast it's true value is not ever seen except for perhaps maybe 50 ms. or less.  Yo creo que

Comment: this could be due to the way you might have scoped your service. Your service will intercept all network requests and apply the logic you have put in. So for example, if you have 2 api calls, when you make the first the interceptor sets the value to true and then in finalize it sets it to false same would happen with the second request as well. 
So you can't guarantee that the this.loading would behave as you are expecting it to.

Comment: what is the scope of this SpinnerService, may be provide it to component level rather than module. so that it creates an instance of itself for each component thereby attaching the loading variable per component. this is has to do with dependency injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem, I created the classes in the same ts file so that it was more ordered, one class is in charge of intercepting the logic and another class is in charge of listening to http requests, I checked many solutions but this was the one that most I liked it because it returns true or false to the html without the need to use dependencies.

this is the ts file of the service you use, you just have to import the service in the component you want to use spinners.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';//para interceptor de http
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';//para interceptor de http
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';//para interceptor de http


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

//servicio interceptor que escucha si hay solicitudes http en progreso
export class interceptHttpService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor(private _pruebaspinerss3 : spinnerService ) { }
  
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
  {    
    this._pruebaspinerss3.requestStarted();    
    return this.handler(next,request);
  }

  handler(next ,request)
  {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
          tap(
            (event) =>{
              if (event instanceof HttpResponse){
                this._pruebaspinerss3.requestEnded();  
              }
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) =>{
              this._pruebaspinerss3.resetSpinner();
              throw error;
            }
          ),
      )
  };
}

export class spinnerService{
  
  private count = 0;
  private spinner$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  
  getSpinnerObserver(): Observable<string>{
    return this.spinner$.asObservable();
  }  

  requestStarted() {
    console.log('spinner activado');   
    if (++this.count === 1) {
      this.spinner$.next('start');
    }
  }

  requestEnded() {
    console.log('spinner desactivado');   
    if (this.count === 0 || --this.count === 0) {
      this.spinner$.next('stop');
    }
  }

  resetSpinner() {
    console.log('error en solicitud, reset spinner');
    this.count = 0;
    this.spinner$.next('stop');
  }
}
```

in file app.module ts

```
import { interceptHttpService, spinnerService } from './services/spinner.service';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to show is a spinner on every http network call made from your application. If that is the case you are almost correct except the public variable 'loading' that you mentioned on the  SpinnerService class.

```
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
export class SpinnerService implements HttpInterceptor{
            
    constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
    {
        this.spinner.show();
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                        this.spinner.hide();
                    }
            )
    );
    }
}
```

Please install the

```
npm i ngx-spinner
```

in you app.component.ts

```
<ngx-spinner></ngx-spinner>
```

Please refer:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner

Comment: muchas gracias por contestas, se puede hacer de esa manera, pero no me gustan muchas las dependencias ngx